# Theme inheritance not working _extend.less shouldn't be merged?

Tags: magento2, frontend, less, frontend-error

I have a custom theme, extends the luma theme, everything works properly.
My custom less modifications were added in `web/css/source/_extend.less`

Now I would like to create a subtheme from this custom theme I created previously, but if I add a content to `/web/css/source/_extend.less` the css modifications added in the parent theme are not taken in consideration.

Shouldn't they be merged or how can i add elegantly new modifications to this new subtheme without copying over again the ones from the previous one. (I understand that _theme.less is not merged but from what I read `_extend.less` should be merged)

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is not a bug and seems to be the expected behaviour, here you can find some workarounds https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/8852